# boolean operator does not seem to be working for ascending list function

Tags: python, for-loop

so the problem is as follows I need to create a function that checks a list if its ascending. If it is the function must return True. Furthermore, if the list is composed of zero elements or just one element it must return True. If the list is not ascending it must return False.

I tried to use similar code, but instead of a for loop I used a while loop and a counter, but still couldn't get the function to work.

```
def is_ascending(items): 
    if len(items) == 0 or len(items) == 1:
        return True 
    for i in list(range(len(items))):
        if items[i] >= items[i + 1]:
            return False
            break
        else:
            return True
```

I already tried the following code with the following lists

**Expected result**

[-5, 10, 99, 123456]  :True

[2, 3, 3, 4, 5]       :False

[99]                  :True

[]                    :True

[4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9] :False

[1, 1, 1, 1]          :False

**Unexpected result**

[-5, 10, 99, 123456] :True

[2, 3, 3, 4, 5]      :True --> this is suppose to be false

[99]                 :True

[]                   :True

[4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9] :True --> this is suppose to be false

[1, 1, 1, 1]          :False

Comment: You always return after the first item because when `i == 0` you either reach `return False` or `return True`. You want to put `return True` outside the loop. (Also you don't need the break, return implies break).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` + `sorted` on list and compare with the original list:

```
def is_ascending(items): 
    return sorted(set(items)) == items
```

**Problem** with your code:

- It returns a `True` / `False` in the first iteration itself depending on whether first item is greater than or equal to second. You never compared all elements.

**Corrected code**:

```
def is_ascending(items): 
    if len(items) == 0 or len(items) == 1:
        return True 
    for i in range(len(items) - 1):
        if items[i] >= items[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, you got rid of the else statement in my for loop because it would return the True value and exit and this made it so the loop didn't iterate over the entire list. Further, I don't quite understand why you changed list(range(len(items))) to range(len(items)-1)

Comment: @SyedAllayAli, that assumption on `else` is correct. Why the `range` is changed is because when `i` becomes the index of last element, inside loop you are trying to fetch element in `i+1`th position which does not exist and would result in `IndexError`. To avoid this, we purposefully iterate only till the second last element.

Comment: I struggled with this for so long, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic approach is to compare zipped tuples, which might be a little easier to read and reason about than for loops and indexes. It will also bail early (like your current idea) on long lists if there's a false value:

```
def is_ascending(items): 
    return all(i < j for i, j in zip(items, items[1:]))


is_ascending([2, 3, 3, 4, 5])  # False
is_ascending([99])             # True
is_ascending([2, 3, 4, 5, 15]) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic is correct. Just check the following corrections and it works fine.

1. Check the range in the for loop
2. return True must be outside else.

In the case where return True is inside else, the condition returns if the first number is less than second and thus doesn't check for other numbers in the list.

Check the code with these changes:

```
def is_ascending(items): 
    if len(items) == 0 or len(items) == 1:
        return True 
    for i in list(range(len(items) - 1)):
        if items[i] >= items[i + 1]:
            return False
            break
    return True
```

Hope this helps!